# What is the difference between i8080 and i8080a?

Tags: 8080

There is some info over the net regarding 'some i8080 bugs were fixed in i8080a', but the exact bugs and differences are not usually disclosed. So, what is the exact difference between i8080 and i8080a?

Answer (score 4):

I googled for the same question and the only [possible answer I found](http://marc.info/?t=104965277200005&r=1&w=2) was that the 8080 wasn't able to connect to standard TTL (only to low power TTL). The 8080A was.

Comment: Perhaps you want to quote the relevant portions of the answer here, as well as the original author, in case the link goes down?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I prefer not to do that since the reference is a (long) discussion between persons that do not agree entirely.

Comment: @ELDendo In situations such as this I usually use lots of ellipsis (`[...]`) and insertions for context `[insertion]`.